# Hit count/ number of page visits in D7

Tags: 7

How to implement a hit counter for all 'Article' type nodes? I want to display number of times (could be unique) a node was visited - perhaps within the teaser and at the bottom of the node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Drupal, you already have that module. You just need to activate Statistic module and set the rights permissions to anonymous users. And maybe you might modify your `node.tpl.php` to show count information.

Also, this module provides you blocks that show the most viewed nodes in the day, all the time or right now.